# Dual monitor + 1 tv

Tags: video, multiple-monitors, tv

I have a Gigabyte HD4850 video card([specifications](http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/vga_manual_gv-r485series_e.pdf)). I want to connect 2 monitors and a TV. The TV could be a clone of one of the monitors. Right now I have one monitor and the TV connected with HDMI(using DVI to HDMI adaptor).
I was thinking about using a DVI splitter. Is that a good approach? What about TV-Out?

Note: go to page 6 in the specifications for details about connectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well what are you wanting? Are you wanting one massive display, cloned output, or a mix? How good do you want the quality of the TV? Does your monitor support taking input from s-video?

Note that a DVI splitter will simply clone the image, which might not be what you want.

If quality isn't an issue on the TV, then do the easiest solution and run both monitors to DVI and the TV to S-Video. Quality will be iffy on the TV, but then just stand farther back.

If you absolutely must have great TV quality, then your going to have to sacrifice either an entire monitor, monitor quality, or money for a new card. Using one card, run the TV to the DVI and one of your monitors to S-Video. If you have dual cards, then just use the available DVI ports.

Comment: well, i want the 2 monitors for work and the tv for movies, so, yeah, high quality is a must. i don't mind that the tv will be a clone, i'll probably turn off the monitors when using the tv and viceversa. my current monitor has a dvi input but i think i will buy two identical new ones for this. i don't want to buy a new graphics card

Comment: The issue is that your wanting 3 high quality outputs, and you only have 2 high quality and 1 medium quality. Why not just try the S-Video and see if it looks alright on the TV?

Comment: What about the DVI splitter? Wouldn't that work?

Comment: For cloned output, it actual would. Forgot that you had that. There pretty cheap, even walmart has them.